# Detect break point (changing point) in the profile-python code

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 215 profiles like the attached figure with different index for the break point. How can I find the index of the break point (changing point)? I tried to find it based on the derivation approach but it can accurately detect the index of the break point because of the noise of the data. Is there any Pyhton package that can detect the index of the changing point more accurately?

[image]

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, let me know what you need and I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with geopandas. You'll just need to replace the coords variable values with your own data.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString
import math
from math import atan2


def calc_line_bearing(gdf):
    
    firstpoint = gdf.geometry.coords[0]
    lastpoint = gdf.geometry.coords[-1]
        
    delta_x = lastpoint[0] - firstpoint[0]
    delta_y = lastpoint[1] - firstpoint[1]
        
    bearing = atan2(delta_x, delta_y) * 180 / math.pi
    
    if bearing < 180:
        bearing = bearing + 180 
    else:
        bearing = bearing - 180
    
    if bearing > 180:
        bearing = bearing - 180
        
    return bearing

coords = [((0, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((0, 2), (1, 3))]

# create a gdf with MLS geometry type
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[MultiLineString(coords)])
# convert from MLS to LineString so we can calc bearing for each line segment

gdf = gdf.explode()
# get rid of the multi-index
gdf.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
# add the bearings for each line
gdf['bearing'] = gdf.apply(calc_line_bearing, axis=1)
# add a new column that will show us where the bearing value changes
shift = gdf["bearing"].shift(1)
gdf['break'] = (shift.ne(gdf['bearing']) & shift.notna())

print(gdf)

    geometry                                        bearing break
0   LINESTRING (0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1.00000)   180.0   False
1   LINESTRING (0.00000 1.00000, 0.00000 2.00000)   180.0   False
2   LINESTRING (0.00000 2.00000, 1.00000 3.00000)   45.0    True
```

[image]